# Why cement under upstairs bathroom floor?

Tags: bathroom, floor

I went to tile upstairs bathroom floor and when we pulled up old linoleum and replace subfloor that was rotted we discovered 1 1/2" of concrete poured on top of old subfloor. Why would somebody do this?

Comment: Perfectly normal in an old house or with an old-fashioned tile-setter specing the work. Can't ask for a better tile substrate. https://www.tcnatile.com/faqs/71-thick-setthick-bed.html

Answer (score 5):

It was (and still is) common to float cement on top of the floor for installation of ceramic tile. It provides a level and firm substrate to which tile mortar (thin-set) will adhere. 1 1/2" seems a bit thick though, maybe there were irregularities with the floor which had to be compensated for. I try not to float so thick unless I have to, and now I use cementitious tile backer board when appropriate. Or sometimes I mortar the tile directly to a smooth firm plywood subfloor in new construction applications.

Comment: Perfectly normal thickness for this type of install - it's not thinset, it's not done the same way as thinset. Tile direct to plywood is not a recommended method.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, all due respect, there are polymer fortified thin-set mortars **specifically** designed for direct application to sound plywood flooring that does not exceed maximum deflection specs. I have had very good results, proper application is key. Check it out: http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-118.pdf